# CollectionView Button action to go to another viewcontroller to display array of images

Tags: uicollectionview

I am working on collectionview, i need to display array of items in another viewcontroller through button action, i don't know how to access an array inside the button, can anyone please tell me?
Here is my code below image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TzpD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a simple solution for that .. You just need to add create a variable of same type in next controller.

```
let dataToPass = secondImagesArray
let vc = ImageViewController()
vc.data = dataToPass
navigationController?.push(vc,true)
```

Give it a try. :)

Comment: what is data (vc.data)?